# facebook api - retrieve all tagged friends photos

Tags: php, facebook, api, photos

I'm never used facebook api yet I saw on a blog a piece of code I could use for. It retrieves all tagged photos of our friends and downloads them.

http://www.shelldaemon.com/2014/01/bypass-facebook-photo-verification.html

Yet it is not working since I login, accept the app permissions and it takes me to the login page again. Is there any problem in the code I can fix? I know about php, yet I don't know anything about facebook api.

It would be awesome if someone can see what's the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which login pages does it take you back to? The Facebook login page or your custom login page? In fact the custom login page would be great since the flow of the app is:
Custom login page on local webserver => Facebook-App login page => Download your friend's tagged photos => Custom login page again.

Maybe the code is working but the part where the app is supposed to download is skipped because of missing file permissions (write-permissions to your destination folder) e.g.?

Did you try to inspect what is going on in your browser after you logged in and before you are redirected to the login page again? With Firefox and Chrome you can inspect the website / web application and look at the console there for errors.

You could also try to add some debugging information during download (e.g. add an "echo 'friendname'" into the download-loop.

Hope that helps!